# Why would a working main function show this intellisense error?

Tags: c++, intellisense, program-entry-point

I'm writing a short program to convert a string (consisting of numbers) to an integer. The code runs ok but I keep getting an odd intellisense error on the "int" part of the `int main()` declaration. The error text is: `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`
and shows the first two letters (the "in") in white and the last (the "t") in the yellow that recognized function names are usually tagged with.

Does anyone know what this might be? Is it just an intellisense anomaly or is there something wrong with my code?

Here's the full code listing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int stringConvert(std::string);

int main()
{
    std::string str("123");
    int stringNum = stringConvert(str);
    std::cout << str << " --> " << stringNum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int stringConvert(std::string stringIn)
{
    int n = std::stoi(stringIn);
    std::cout << "String conversion completed" << std::endl;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I found that restarting the IDE can usually clear up these kind of highlighting errors.

Comment: In addition to what @Hitobat said, you should always define all other functions before `main`. `int main()` should be your last function. It is just a good practice.